# Format Code In MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop on Mac to write MonoTouch apps.  Automatica code indenting/formatting works great while I am typing.

The problem is that when I copy and paste code snippets, in many cases I lose the formatting and lines are combined together, indenting is lost, and it is a huge pain to implement the tabs, spacing, and line breaks manually.  Is there anyway I can use a command in monoDevelop to automatically indent and apply the formatting to existing code.

I thought maybe Edit|Format|Format Document/Selection would work, but these commands don't have any affect on the code at all.

Any help?

Comment: Change your formatting settings so that the code is formatted how you like it. Right now, it's formatting your code automatically in the default fashion.

Comment: user1060500, if my answer helped, perhaps you could accept the answer and/or upvote it?  :-D

Answer (score 29):

To format the entire document in one keystroke: `control-I`

To format a selection: `Edit->Format->Format Selection`

To customize the formatting: `MonoDevelop->Preferences->Source Code->Code Formatting`

Comment: keystroke was not set in my case, but added it to key Bindings ­­`Tools->Options->Key Binding` then searched `format`. Thanks!

Comment: Funny as I was struggling to understand the shortcut shown as "^ l" on the menu item. Tried `CTRL`+ all the vertical bar characters I could think of, but did not think about the small cap 'i'... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You actually need to select all your text, and then go to Edit->Format->Format Document. It doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

For me on macOS, the shortcut for "auto-format" is `CTRL + i`.

You can change the shortcut if you want. To change it, go to Preferences -> Key Bindings, then type "format" in the search box and edit the "Format Document" shortcut/key binding.