# Shortcut for formatting code in Monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Is there a way to format code using a keybinding in Monodevelop? [Format Code In MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457236/format-code-in-monodevelop) claims you can use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> but it does not appear to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only workaround I discovered is under

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->Behavior
```

You can check the option `Format document on save` which lets you use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save and format code.

Comment: Actually its better than what I was looking for. Saves you from the second short cut after saving the file :)

Comment: I prefer the keybinding answer below, as I noticed with 'format on save' on, it moves the cursor too, which is quite annoying if I want to quickly save and continue typing.

Answer (score 17):

Tools->Options->Key Bindings

Scroll to 'Edit' section and give a keybinding to the 'Format Document' command

[image]

Brownie points for whoever guesses what IDE I'm used to :D

Comment: still better then netbeans